# ASP.NET Core 5.0 nlog implementation not working

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, nlog

I am working on an application where I want to log an exception but it doesn't work. The error i want to log is basically on validateToken I want to know what exception I am getting.  Here is my implementation I have added all the code which I am using for nLog.

Program.cs

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseNLog()
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                // Remove all the default logging providers
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                logging.AddNLog().SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Error);
            })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

Here is a screenshot of the `nlog.config` file:

[image: nlog.config]

`appSetting.json` settings file:

```
"NLogConnection": {
    "DbProvider": "sqlserver",
    "DbHost": "SQL5103.site4now.net",
    "Database": "db_a7b629_testdatabase",
    "User": "db_a7b629_testdatabase_admin",
    "Password": "Ad*******"
  },
```

Here is where I want to log exception

```
public class UserProfileInfo : IUserProfileInfo
{
    private readonly IHttpNetClientService _apiService;
    protected readonly IOptions<AppSettingDTO.AppSettingDTO> _appSetting;
    private readonly ILogger<UserProfileInfo> _logger;

    public UserProfileInfo(ILogger<UserProfileInfo> logger, IHttpNetClientService HttpClient, IOptions<AppSettingDTO.AppSettingDTO> AppSettings)
    {
        _apiService = HttpClient;
        _appSetting = AppSettings;
        this._logger = logger;
    }
    
    public bool ValidateToken(string token)
    {
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        try
        {
            tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidIssuer = _appSetting.Value.Jwt.Issuer,
                ValidAudience = _appSetting.Value.Jwt.Audience,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_appSetting.Value.Jwt.Key)),
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            }, out SecurityToken validatedToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // this where I want to log an exception but it is not working .. and always log me an error in the txt file generated in c:\temp folder 
            this._logger.LogError($"---- Token Error ----", ex.Message);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Error log in txt file

```
2021-10-26 13:38:28.8797 Info Message Template Auto Format enabled
2021-10-26 13:38:28.8797 Info Loading assembly: NLog.Web.AspNetCore
2021-10-26 13:38:28.9069 Info Adding target DatabaseTarget(Name=database)
2021-10-26 13:38:28.9335 Info Validating config: TargetNames=database, ConfigItems=33, FilePath=C:\Kamran  Don't Delete\SAUFIK\Project Files\GMD\GMDAPI\GMDApi\bin\Debug\net5.0\NLog.config
2021-10-26 13:38:28.9582 Info Configuration initialized.
2021-10-26 13:38:28.9582 Info NLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c. File version: 4.7.9.12899. Product version: 4.7.9+e8712e62842e2d74d60fdf37cf74d743750e5ca2. GlobalAssemblyCache: False
```

The above error which is log into the default txt file when there is an exception but nothing in the database I don't know may be there something wrong with my UserProfileinfo class.

Answer (score 1):

The logging rules decides where logger-output should be written. Your logging-rules says that ONLY loggers with name `database` should be write to the `database`-target:

```xml
<rules>
   <logger name="database" minlevel="error" writeto="database" />
</rules>
```

But in your code you are using `ILogger<UserProfileInfo>`, that will have logger-name based on `typeof(UserProfileInfo).Name`.

If you just want ALL errors independent of logger-name, then just use `*`-wildcard:

```xml
<rules>
   <logger name="*" minlevel="error" writeto="database" />
</rules>
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial

See also: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-GetCurrentClassLogger-and-Microsoft-ILogger